# Issues with cordova and android studio

Tags: android, cordova

I have downloaded android studio, installed ant, node.js, cordova and jdk
But I can not add platform to my cordova android app
Here is the bashrc file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/Dev/android-studio/sdk/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/Dev/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools
```

Whenever I try to add platform under my created app project it throws error:

```
Creating android project...

/home/anupam/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at /home/anupam/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (/home/anupam/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /home/anupam/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/home/anupam/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/anupam/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /home/anupam/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/home/anupam/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
Error: /home/anupam/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

I an tired of searching all the answers in stackoverflow and google. Not a single guide could solve my problem. Just one thing I want to use ANdroid studio, not eclipse. SO please do not mention eclipse workarounds. If there is any clean install method , please mention if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - if you have eclipse installed prior your cordova installation, then you probably don't have the latest API updates.

Run android from your command line to open your SDK Manager - or find it in your android installation root folder (for CLI - Use Administrator) - or simply from your eclipse UI command.

In here find where updates are needed and install and run your android installation as you did before cordova platform add android

Comment: as I said please do not suggest eclipse workarounds. However I had to move back to eclipse as no one provided me solution for that